# How to change loop data value with another outside loop data value

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

```
<div id="core-a">
    <div class="name">A</div>
    <div class="age">B</div>
</div>

<div id="core-b">
    <div class="left-slide">Dog</div>
    <div class="right-slide">1990</div>
</div>
```

I want to use **document.querySelectorAll** to change innerHTML or loopover like that
Example:

**.name** selector innerHTML replace with Dog

**.age** selector innerHTML replace with 1990

I am out ideas how to achieve that, but i don't want to use jQuery for that as i have it, Pure JS solution will be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to do it is with ES6 features:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.name')] // This will transform NodeList in array
     .forEach(tag => tag.innerHTML='<SOMETHING>');
```

If you are looking just to one single HTML tag with that class name you can use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`:

```js
document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML = '<SOMETHING>';
```

Btw I suggest to use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks, I know the use of querySelectorAll, but  i don't want to use an static text, i want dynamic text which will come from another dynamic selector, Please check my example

Comment: Did you consider to use `document.querySelector('.name').innerText = document.querySelector('.left-slide').innerText`?

Comment: Yes i want like that, but with loop, as i have same thing multiple times

Comment: What do you mean "same thing multiple times"?  You should describe better your problem to let me find a more appropriate solution. For what I see in your code there is no possibility to improve the solution with a loop.